# Is there a straightforward way to change how pandas prints integer nulls?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pretty-print Pandas DataFrames with nullable integer content.  The `DataFrame.to_string()` method has an optional argument, `na_rep`, which you can use to override how floating-point nulls are printed.  In Pandas 1.2.4 at least, it doesn't appear to affect how nullable integer objects are printed.  In the minimal example below, the method returns the string `"<NA>"` when I want a blank.

Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

print(f"\nPandas version = {pd.__version__}")

index = list("abcd")
columns = list("efghjk")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, dtype=pd.Int32Dtype())
for df in (df1, df2):
    df.at["c", "h"] = 7 # Some non-null content
    print("\n", df.to_string(na_rep=""))
```

Output:

```
Pandas version = 1.2.4

   e f g  h j k
a             
b             
c        7    
d             

       e     f     g     h     j     k
a  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
b  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
c  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     7  <NA>  <NA>
d  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Very interesting that `na_rep` is specifically setup to _ignore_ `NaN` adjacent types specifically `pd.NA`, `None`, and `pd.NaT` will use their own formatting before considering `self.na_rep`. Source for format (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/formats/format.py#L1299) MRE -> `pd.DataFrame([[pd.NA, np.nan, pd.NaT, None]]).to_string(na_rep='-')`

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you, that is interesting, and I wonder why.  So it looks like I might have to do something clunky to achieve the result I want.

Comment: If you're in a jupyter notebook [Styler.format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) handles all `NaN`-like values appropriately -> `pd.DataFrame([[pd.NA, np.nan, pd.NaT, None]]).style.format(na_rep='-')` The source for styler.format na_rep (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.3/pandas/io/formats/style_render.py#L1004)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
import pandas as pd

print(f"\nPandas version = {pd.__version__}")

index = list("abcd")
columns = list("efghjk")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, dtype=pd.Int32Dtype())
for df in (df1, df2):
    df.at["c", "h"] = 7 # Some non-null content
    print("\n", df.astype('float64').to_string(float_format='%d', na_rep=""))
```